# .NET 4.5 Web Forms Included Javascript - What are these files?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net-4.5

In the latest 2013 VS preview when you create a basic asp.net web forms page it generates a basic site, with the following JS files referenced and included in the project.

Now I notice that for example the WebForms.js appears to deal with postback etc, however I'm wondering with regards to a lot of the others if they are required if I'm planning to roll my own treeviews, gridviews etc?

Which of these files am I safe to remove if I don't plan to use the UI (bootstrap) provided?

```
<asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
<asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
<asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
<asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
<asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
<asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
<asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
<asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This blog about the Asp.Net scriptManager may help for your issue.

[ASP.NET 4.5 ScriptManager Improvements in WebForms](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/09/21/asp-net-4-5-scriptmanager-improvements-in-webforms.aspx)